# Relational database structure design

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I am designing a database in MySQL and need some guidance on how it should be structured and the relationships between tables. I have identified the following facts:

I have:

- many users. (Fine)
- One user has many organisations. (One - Many)
- One organisation has many events. (One - Many)
- One user has many addresses. (One - Many)
- One organisation has many addresses (One - Many), but these addresses could be used by another organisation or event. Thus many organisations have many addresses. (Many - Many)
- One event has one address. (One - One)
- One organisation has one main address, but many organisations could be working from the same address, so (Many - One)

This is where I am stuck, because although an organisation or event has an address, they do not own it, the user does. So are these relationships necessary? Do I need to define foreign key relationships or can I get away without them? Do I need to maintain a separate table of default addresses because 2 organisations could use the same address but it not be the default address of one, so referencing it in the address table would be problematic (which one is actually the main address)?

Or am I looking at this in too complicated a way? Perhaps have the user maintain the addresses, then when they add an organisation, the organisation references that address but knows nothing of the other addresses (is that a one - one relationship for organisations or a many - one for addresses? Clearly removal of an organisation shouldn't mean the removal of an address and vice versa).

Then, when an event is added, it also just references an address, but can lookup the default address of the organisation to which it belongs. The same questions arise as above. The event is at that address but the address doesn't belong to the event or vice versa.

That almost simplifies it to:

- One user, many events.
- One user, many organisations.
- One user, many addresses.
- One organisation, one address.
- One event, one address.

Is this the correct way to be looking at this problem? Are there any difficulties that could arise that I don't appear to have considered? Is there a better way to tackle this? The biggest problem I have is how to relate the tables to each other so I can set the relationships accordingly.

-- Edit: Added Info

Thinking about it further, more than one organisation might be having the same event. I would like to be able to link events also. These organisations could be added by separate users, but all need to be related. Is this something that MySQL can handle easily or should I be looking at other types of database logic such as graph databases?

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on your use case.  Sure, having a user or organization share an address (so, an addresses table) might seem technically correct, but it is probably adding unnecessary complexity.  Think about how you're going to query your database (try to be forward thinking - what stuff might you want to do later?) and design your tables to support those queries.

You don't have to have foreign key constraints in your database.  Actually, most databases I've looked at *don't* have them, the business logic handles checking the integrity of the records.  I would suggest, again, that you be pragmatic about it and do what you are comfortable building and supporting.

Comment: At least have the courtesy to *explain* the downvote (technically incorrect, unhelpful, etc.?).  Thanks.

Comment: It certainly wasn't me, I don't have enough points to down vote!

Comment: I can only speculate but the *"You don't have to have foreign key constraints in your database. Actually, most databases I've looked at don't have them, the business logic handles checking the integrity of the records."* is probably the offending part.

Comment: Well, thanks for the guess, but it's still an accurate description of my observations.